# Mandrill API email getting Queued with use of Template

Tags: php, email, templates, mandrill

I am trying to use mandrill api for sending emails with template. I am working on method documented here: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html#method=send-template
Code is implemented in URL: http://ezaccom.com/mxl.php
My problem is that all of my emails are getting queued instead of sending quickly as they should. Here is code (Note %TEMPLATE CODE% is where my email template goes):

```
 try {
$mandrill = new Mandrill('API_KEY_REDACTED');
$template_name = 'Welcome mail on email /FB sign-up to very email id';
$template_content = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Welcome mail on email /FB sign-up to very email id',
        'content' => 'sign-up'
    )
);
$message = array(
    'html' => '%TEMPLATE CODE%',
    'text' => 'Example text content',
    'subject' => 'Welcome to Easyaccom',
    'from_email' => 'hello@easyaccom.com',
    'from_name' => 'Easyaccom',
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'RECIPIENT@gmail.com',
            'name' => 'Jordan Belfort',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
    ),
    'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'message.reply@example.com'),
    'important' => false,
    'track_opens' => null,
    'track_clicks' => null,
    'auto_text' => null,
    'auto_html' => null,
    'inline_css' => null,
    'url_strip_qs' => null,
    'preserve_recipients' => null,
    'view_content_link' => null,
    'bcc_address' => 'message.bcc_address@example.com',
    'tracking_domain' => null,
    'signing_domain' => null,
    'return_path_domain' => null,
    'merge' => true,
    'merge_language' => 'mailchimp',
    'global_merge_vars' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'merge1',
            'content' => 'merge1 content'
        )
    ),
    'merge_vars' => array(
        array(
            'rcpt' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
            'vars' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'merge2',
                    'content' => 'merge2 content'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'tags' => array('password-resets'),
    'subaccount' => 'customer-123',
    'google_analytics_domains' => array('example.com'),
    'google_analytics_campaign' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
    'metadata' => array('website' => 'www.example.com'),
    'recipient_metadata' => array(
        array(
            'rcpt' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
            'values' => array('user_id' => 123456)
        )
    ),
    'attachments' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'text/plain',
            'name' => 'myfile.txt',
            'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
        )
    ),
    'images' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'image/png',
            'name' => 'IMAGECID',
            'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
        )
      )
    );
   $async = false;
$ip_pool = 'Main Pool';
$send_at = 'example send_at';
$result = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message, $async, $ip_pool);
print_r($result);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => recipient.email@example.com
            [status] => sent
            [reject_reason] => hard-bounce
            [_id] => abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123
        )

)
*/
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
// Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
// A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
throw $e;
  }
   ?>
```

Comment: And where is the question ?

Comment: Edited the description but the title says it all: emails are getting queued instead of sending them quickly. I am never able to receive the emails. Though there is no error being shown.

Comment: How do you know the email is being queued? Does it show up in Mandrill analytics or logs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a lot of optional parameters that you're not setting explicitly, including `attachments` and `images` which will automatically result in the call being processed asynchronously (and the `queued` response). If you remove those, you should see errors returned to you, which should highlight things like having a subaccount that doesn't exist and an invalid `send_at` date. In general, you should remove **all** optional parameters except those that you're explicitly setting.

Also, if you're using a template (and sending with send-template), you don't need to provide the template code in the `html` parameter. That will be ignored if your stored template in Mandrill has HTML; you need to only provide the `html` if the stored Mandrill template doesn't already have HTML.

For your security, and for Mandrill's, since the API key was posted publicly, it's been disabled, and I've edited the original post to remove it. You should generate another one and not use the one posted here going forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am happy to see that you have taken time without any email regarding this page. The issues are now fixed. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

Just cut all unused parameters

```js
try {
$mandrill = new Mandrill('API_KEY_REDACTED');
$template_name = 'Welcome mail on email /FB sign-up to very email id';
$template_content = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Welcome mail on email /FB sign-up to very email id',
        'content' => 'sign-up'
    )
);
$message = array(
    'html' => '%TEMPLATE CODE%',
    'text' => 'Example text content',
    'subject' => 'Welcome to Easyaccom',
    'from_email' => 'hello@easyaccom.com',
    'from_name' => 'Easyaccom',
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'RECIPIENT@gmail.com',
            'name' => 'Jordan Belfort',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
    ),
    'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'message.reply@example.com'),
    'important' => false,
    'track_opens' => null,
    'track_clicks' => null,
    'auto_text' => null,
    'auto_html' => null,
    'inline_css' => null
    );
   $async = false;

$result = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message, $async);
print_r($result);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => recipient.email@example.com
            [status] => sent
            [reject_reason] => hard-bounce
            [_id] => abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123
        )

)
*/
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
// Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
// A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
throw $e;
  }
   ?>
```